# How to add blank space in parameter dialogs

Tags: modelica, dymola

I would like to add vertical blank space between two lines in a Modelica component GUI.  I have (in this case), six similar looking parameters/comments within a group on a tab that I would like to visually break into two plus four by using a little space after the second one (essentially a blank line, but ideally I would have some control over the gap space).

I can put the last four in a separate group with no name, which gives a line in between the two/four.  This is better than nothing, but not really what I want.  I tried using groupImage, but it locates the image relative to whole group, so if it's smaller than the six entries, it doesn't affect them at all; and if it's larger, it introduces uniform spacing between all the entries, rather than just between 2/3.

Comment: So you have several parameters in one group and you want to add a space in between? This is not possible. You can put your parameters in groups and tabs, that's it. Just make two groups out of it.

Comment: @marco Yes, that is what I was looking to do.  Thanks for the feedback.